# Distribution of $Z = X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are geometric random variables with different parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can you please help me out with following problem:

There are $2$ independent random variables geometric distributed, $X$ and $Y$.
They have different parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$, both from $(0,1)$ interval, $p_1\neq p_2$. How to find distribution of $Z$, where $Z = X + Y$ ?

If $p_1=p_2$, it would be negative binomial, but if $p_1\neq p_2$, I am not sure.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have suppressed "geometric probability" tag: look at its description, it's a completely different theme.

Comment: You are right, unless $r_1=r_2$, it is not ranked as a "classical" probability distribution. The simplest way to work it through the product of their probability generating functions (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Generating_Function_of_Geometric_Distribution)

Comment: You need to specify which of the alternative Geometric models you are using (counting from 0, or from 1 etc)

Comment: @wolfies You are right, the answers by JimmyK4542 and myself implicitly use the counting from $0$. We should all the time give this precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\Pr[X = n] = p_1(1-p_1)^n$ and $\Pr[Y = n] = p_2(1-p_2)^n$ for $n = 0,1,2,\ldots$, where $p_1 \neq p_2$. Then, for any $n = 0,1,2,\ldots$, we have:

$\Pr[Z = n]$ $= \Pr[X+Y = n]$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\Pr[X = k \ \text{AND} \ Y = n-k]$

$\overset{(1)}{=} \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\Pr[X = k]\Pr[Y = n-k]$ $= \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}p_1(1-p_1)^kp_2(1-p_2)^{n-k}$

$= p_1p_2(1-p_2)^n\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1-p_1}{1-p_2}\right)^k$ $\overset{(2)}{=} p_1p_2(1-p_2)^n\dfrac{1-\left(\tfrac{1-p_1}{1-p_2}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\tfrac{1-p_1}{1-p_2}}$

$= p_1p_2\dfrac{(1-p_2)^{n+1}}{1-p_2}\dfrac{1-\left(\tfrac{1-p_1}{1-p_2}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\tfrac{1-p_1}{1-p_2}}$ $= \dfrac{p_1p_2\left[(1-p_2)^{n+1}-(1-p_1)^{n+1}\right]}{(1-p_2)-(1-p_1)}$

$= \dfrac{p_1p_2\left[(1-p_2)^{n+1}-(1-p_1)^{n+1}\right]}{p_1-p_2}$.

$(1)$ This follows since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

$(2)$ Here, we have used the formula for the sum of a geometric series, and the fact that $p_1 \neq p_2$.

I'm not sure if this distribution has a name.

Comment: Should this sum goes **from 0 to n or** or **from 1 to n** ? @JimmyK4542

Comment: I'm using the convention that a geometric random variable can take the values $0,1,2,\ldots$. With this convention, $(X,Y) = (0,n)$ and $(X,Y) = (n,0)$ are both ways for which $Z = X+Y = n$. Hence, $k = 0$ and $k = n$ need to be included in the summation. If you are using the convention that a geometric random variable takes the values $1,2,\ldots$ (i.e. zero is not included) then you should adjust the expressions for $\Pr[X = n]$, $\Pr[Y = n]$, and the bounds for the summation accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for detail explanation!
If I may ask for one more clarification - can you please explain sum of geometric series in one or two more steps? @JimmyK4542

Comment: I've added a few steps to the part where I evaluate the sum of the geometric series. Let me know if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: It is all clear now, thank you once again, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The computation given upwards by @JimmyK4542 can be somewhat simplified and, I would say, appear more natural, by using probability generating functions (pgfs). Here is how.

The pgf of a random variable $X$ with geometric distribution Geo(p) is :

$$g_X(s):=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X=k)s^k=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}pq^ks^k=\dfrac{p}{1-qs} \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ q:=1-p$$

Knowing that the pgf of the sum $Z:=X_1+X_2$ of 2 independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ is the product of their pgf, we have, here,  with indexed notations:

$$g_{Z}(s)=\dfrac{p_1}{1-q_1s} \times \dfrac{p_2}{1-q_2s}$$

Using partial fraction decomposition:

$$g_{Z}(s)=r\left(q_2\dfrac{1}{1-q_2s}-q_1\dfrac{1}{1-q_1s}\right) \ \ \text{with} \ \ r:=\dfrac{p_1p_2}{p_1-p_2}$$

Expanding the two fractions inside the parentheses into geometrical series gives the desired result:

$$ g_{Z}(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\underbrace{r(q_2^{n+1}-q_1^{n+1})}_{P(Z=n)}s^n$$